# To find the orthogonal trajectories of differential equation with attempt

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question is to find orthogonal trajectories of one parameter of family of curves given by
$$x^2 - y^2 +1=\lambda xy.$$ 
And thus solve this equation.

By doing an usual method for this question I have reached up to the 
$$(x + xy^{2} ) dx + ( y^{3} +x^{2}y -y -x^{3}y)dy=0.$$ 
Now, how do I solve from here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: if you have a differential equation $P(x,y)dx + Q(x,y)dy = 0$ it describes a vector field on plane: at each point $(x,y)$ you have a vector $(P(x,y), Q(x,y))$ and that vector is tangent to some curve from your family. If orthogonal trajectory passes through the point then it's tangent vector should be just orthogonal to $(P(x,y), Q(x,y))$. W.l.o.g. you could write that orthogonal trajectories satisfy differential equation generated by $(-Q(x,y), P(x,y))$ vector field. Here you go.